# Spring + maven + custom keystore = maven build error

Tags: java, maven

I'm facing a problem when maven building my springboot project containing the keystore and truststore. I have a separate keystore and truststore that I use to communicate with my mongo replica (x509). To do so, I generated pragmatically the ssl context and pass it to the MongoClient and this works. This is where I initiate the MongoClient (for the moment is in the Application main class:

```
    @Value("${mongo.keyStore}")
    private String keyStore;
    @Value("${mongo.keyStorePassword}")
    private String keyStorePassword;
    @Value("${mongo.trustStore}")
    private String trustStore;
    @Value("${mongo.trustStorePassword}")
    private String trustStorePassword;
    @Value("${mongo.keyAlias}")
    private String keyAlias;
    @Value("${mongo.subject}")
    private String subject;

    @Bean
    public SSLContext mongoSSLContext() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(keyStore)) {
            keystore.load(in, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
        }
        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory =
                KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        keyManagerFactory.init(keystore, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());

        KeyStore ts = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(trustStore)) {
            ts.load(in, trustStorePassword.toCharArray());
        }
        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        trustManagerFactory.init(ts);

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());

        return sslContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public X509Certificate mongoClientCertificate() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(keyStore)) {
            keystore.load(in, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
        }
        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory =
                KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        keyManagerFactory.init(keystore, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
        X509KeyManager keyManager = (X509KeyManager) keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers()[0];
        return keyManager.getCertificateChain(keyAlias)[0];
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoClientSettingsBuilderCustomizer mongoSslCustomizer(SSLContext mongoSSLContext) {
        return clientSettingsBuilder -> clientSettingsBuilder.applyToSslSettings(sslBuilder -> sslBuilder.context(mongoSSLContext));
    }
```

and here are my configs:

```
mongo:
    trustStore: ${PWD}/src/main/resources/keystore/ts.keystore
    trustStorePassword: <password>
    keyStore: ${PWD}/src/main/resources/keystore/ks.jks
    keyStorePassword: <password>
    keyAlias: <key-alias>
    subject: <subject>
```

The keystore and truststore reside in src/main/resources.
At the moment the application starts up correctly. But when I issue the `mvn clean package`, I get the error of malformed input, which is coming from the keystore and truststore files. I tried to remove them from the project and place them somewhere else at installation time, but it is complaining because the files are not found.

I suspect that I'm not doing this correctly... Can someone help?

Thank you!

Comment: My assumption. Have you configured to filter your resources?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this out in your pom.xml ?

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.keystore</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*.jks</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.keystore</include>
                <include>**/*.jks</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>

    </resources>
```

Comment: Hi Sorin, I've managed to make it work by filtering the two files. However, is there a way to avoid packaging the keystore and truststore within the jar? I've tried that, but I get file not found. Thank you